# Laravel4 how to switch database name at runtime

Tags: laravel-4

Laravel4 how to switch database name at runtime.

I know there is a way to change the database config.

```
Schema::connection('foo')->create('users', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
});
```

But I need to create many databases. Can not write them all in a file database.php.

thank for advance

Comment: do you mean define and use new connection at runtime ?

Comment: yes sir. How can i defie new conection at runtime. Actually i want to change only database name. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found a solution.

```
    Config::set('database.connections.mysqlCustom.database','databaseName');

    Schema::connection('mysqlCustom')->create('product', function(Blueprint $table ) {    
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Hopefully it will help people who have problem like me.